# Servlet Mapping not working in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets, mapping

Hi I have made an application in eclipse that is Google App Engine Project.
It works fine on my localhost I have deployed it on GAE.

All Static page like login, signup pages are displayed but when I am sending request to servlet from my jsp page it shows me an error.

Suppose I have opened page login.jsp and when I click on login button it shows me an error something like :

```
Error: Not Found

The requested URL /Dologin was not found on this server.
```

I have defined all my servlet files in `com` package under `src` folder.
Before this I am getting error of `webservlet annotation` but I have added `tomcat server` in my library in `build path`, all that error gone but now this servlet mapping error comes in.

web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pj.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/prj/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>signup.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

[here is mt base/main page](http://1-dot-keyurdatadrive.appspot.com/signup.jsp) of Google app engine deployed project.

Anyone please help me.

Comment: show us your web.xml plz

Comment: @M.Sameer - I have updated question with `web.xml`

Comment: You have not configured any servlet to handle /DoLogin in your web.xml

Comment: @M.Sameer - How to configure servlet for that because in my app I have used webservlet annotation so it don't need any configuration in web.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Before this I am getting error of webservlet annotation but I have added tomcat server in my library in build path, all that error gone but now this servlet mapping error comes in.

From the above description it seems that you are using `javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet` annotation to configure your environment. The annotation-based servlet configuration is supported as of servlet 3.0 specification, however, servlet API supported by App Engine is 2.5 at the time of this writing. Remove all such annotations and configure your environment by means of `web.xml` descriptor only.

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3091) you can find App Engine feature request for Servlet API 3.0.

Comment: Sir now what I ll have to do ? Shall I ve to `remove all annotation` and have to `manually map servlet using web.xml` ? And sir In my code I have used upload mechanism using `Part`, so it showing me error on that also. Any idea why it's behaving like that ?

Comment: Yes, remove all annotations related to Servlet 3.0 API and define your servlets along with their mappings in web.xml. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet) regarding to file upload.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are missing the path in the method of greetServlet. I guess **greetServlet** is your servlet, and inside you have foo method:

```
@Path("/Dologin") //add this before your method
public String foo(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {...}
```